# incompatible types error when providing a String to a method which requires a String

Tags: java, string

i am trying to pass a String value into a method which accepts Strings, however i am getting the error "incompatible types". i have tried hard coding a int value to see what error it gives which i expected it to:

*found int; required: java.lang.String.*

changed the method to accept File instead which errors:

*found String; required: java.io.File.*

ergo, i am feeding a string where a string should be. but i don't understand where i am going wrong. (and i have changed it back to feed String and accept String)

any feedback is welcome. thanks in advance :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test
{
    private ArgsReader inputFile;
    private String filename;
    private List<Pallet> entryBayQueue;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Test
     */
    public Test()
    {
        inputFile = new ArgsReader();
        entryBayQueue = new LinkedList();
    }

    /**
     * methods
     */
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        if(args.length > 0) //launched if you gave an argument
        {
            String line;
            filename = args[0];
            System.out.println(filename.getClass().getSimpleName()); //outputs string


            line = inputFile.stringFileReader(filename); //call method containing reading capability to read and store contents in line

            // ******* here is where the error occurs

            //System.out.println(line); //line = null here
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);//tokenize line's contents
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                int serialNum = 0;
                switch(st.nextToken())
                {
                    case "A": 
                        {
                            serialNum++;
                            Pallet almondPallet = new Pallet(1,serialNum); //create new almond pellet and assign serial number
                            entryBayQueue.add(almondPallet); //adds pallet to the end of the list
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

        }
        else //launched when you didn't provide an argument
        {
            filename = null;
            Console console = System.console();
            filename = console.readLine("file to read from: ");
            inputFile.stringFileReader(filename); //call method containing reading capability
        }
    }
}

// ******this is the implementation of stringFileReader

public void stringFileReader(String filename)
    {
        try
        {            
            input = new FileReader(filename); //open file for reading (string filename)
            buffReader = new BufferedReader(input); // read a line at a time

            line = buffReader.readLine(); //read 1st line
            while (line != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
                System.out.println(line);
                line = buffReader.readLine(); //read next line
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e){System.out.println("caught IOException");}
```

Comment: Obviously your method is taking a `File` as parameter and not a `String`. You have shown a lot of code and none of it is relevant: show the method declaration of `stringFileReader`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel i have edited the question to suit what you are asking for. method is definitely not taking a File

Comment: Can you create a short code sample that demonstrates the problem? Something that we can execute as well.

Comment: You should be able to do this in 10 lines.  However, I predict when you try you will be unable to duplicate this problem.  You are doing something else wrong and misinterpreting the error.

At the very least, include ALL your code and display the exact error.  Is this a compile error or a stack trace? Either way, you are getting line numbers.  You have to share all your information.

Comment: Please don't share ALL your code, share the relevant code. It's already to much unnecessary code here, nobody will read this. And share the error message - the exact error message.

Comment: @Dov Thomas the exact compile error i am getting is literally "incompatible types". i have explained my troubleshooting steps in the question as well and jeroen i don't understand what you mean as something you can execute because there's really no way i am posting all my classes up on here where they all aggregate with each other.

Comment: @Ryane,
Glad you found your error, but you don't seem to understand how to communicate if you want others to help you.  If you got a compile time error, then at the very least it told you what line it was on.  What you needed to show us was the call line, the function it was calling, and the error message. Not your impression of the error message.
    RegexTest.java:13: error: ')' expected
                System.out.println(s1.r     eplaceAll("\\w+", "1"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void stringFileReader(String filename)
```

was supposed to be

```
public String stringFileReader(String filename)
```

method was not returning values when call is expecting.

thanks anyone who was helping.